# SpringBoot: can we place InputStreamResource inside DTO

Tags: java, inputstream, lombok, dto

Whether we can place `InputStreamResource` inside DTO and return to Frontend via Restful API

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class MySimpleDTO implements Serializable {

    private InputStreamResource file;
    private String fileName;
}
```

Comment: If you want to share a file as your response you can make your API return type as `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>`.